# Increment automatically the version of an assembly but without the default scheme

Tags: c#, .net

I am using `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]` but the version is `1.0.5162.31898` and i only want `1.0.5, 1.0.6` etc..

Comment: Where is `1.0.5, 1.0.6` coming from?

Comment: [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.crowsprogramming.com/archives/27) or [Build Version Increment Add-In Visual Studio](http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Something for visual studio 2013 ?

Comment: Why dont you use some continuous integration software to generate that for you?

Comment: Can i have recommendation ?